# SmallChange in a XAML ScrollViewer ControlTemplate has no effect

Tags: wpf, xaml

I've created a basic Windows Desktop WPF Application.  In the MainWindow, I've added the following as the body of the window:

```
    <ScrollViewer Template="{DynamicResource ScrollViewerControlTemplate1}">
        <ScrollViewer.Resources>
            <ControlTemplate x:Key="ScrollViewerControlTemplate1" TargetType="{x:Type ScrollViewer}">
                <Grid x:Name="Grid" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Rectangle x:Name="Corner" Grid.Column="1" Fill="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}}" Grid.Row="1"/>
                    <ScrollContentPresenter x:Name="PART_ScrollContentPresenter" CanContentScroll="{TemplateBinding CanContentScroll}" CanHorizontallyScroll="False" CanVerticallyScroll="False" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" Grid.Column="0" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" Grid.Row="0"/>
                    <ScrollBar x:Name="PART_VerticalScrollBar" AutomationProperties.AutomationId="VerticalScrollBar" Cursor="Arrow" Grid.Column="1" Maximum="{TemplateBinding ScrollableHeight}" Minimum="0" Grid.Row="0" Visibility="{TemplateBinding ComputedVerticalScrollBarVisibility}" Value="{Binding VerticalOffset, Mode=OneWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" ViewportSize="{TemplateBinding ViewportHeight}" SmallChange="40000"/>
                    <ScrollBar x:Name="PART_HorizontalScrollBar" AutomationProperties.AutomationId="HorizontalScrollBar" Cursor="Arrow" Grid.Column="0" Maximum="{TemplateBinding ScrollableWidth}" Minimum="0" Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Row="1" Visibility="{TemplateBinding ComputedHorizontalScrollBarVisibility}" Value="{Binding HorizontalOffset, Mode=OneWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" ViewportSize="{TemplateBinding ViewportWidth}"/>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </ScrollViewer.Resources>
        <Grid Margin="20">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="300"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="300"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="300"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="300"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="300"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <Border Grid.Row="0" Background="SteelBlue"/>
            <Border Grid.Row="1" Background="Peru"/>
            <Border Grid.Row="2" Background="Goldenrod"/>
            <Border Grid.Row="3" Background="Tomato"/>
            <Border Grid.Row="4" Background="IndianRed"/>
        </Grid>

    </ScrollViewer>
```

You'll notice that on PART_VerticalScrollbar, I've set the SmallChange="40000" (an arbitrarily large number).  Yet when I click the up/down arrows on the scrollbar, it does the same very small change as it did before I set the SmallChange to anything.

I've read over the documentation a number of times, and can't figure out why this isn't having any effect on the amount that the ScrollViewer scrolls.  Any ideas?

Note that I could change the ScrollBar template and change the command these button calls to Scrollbar.PageUpCommand rather than Scrollbar.LineUpCommand, but ultimately I'd like to have finer control over the scrolling than a full page.

Answer (score 1):

The reason for this is a special logic implemented in the `ScrollViewer` and in the `ScrollBar`.

The `ScrollBar.SmallChange` property will be only considered for scrolling if the scroll bar is stand-alone. That means, when it is outside of a `ScrollViewer`.

If you look at the `ScrollViewer.OnApplyTemplate` [method](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationFramework/src/Framework/System/Windows/Controls/ScrollViewer.cs,b3cec2f89df004cd), you will notice the following:

```
public override void OnApplyTemplate()
{
    // ...
    ScrollBar scrollBar = GetTemplateChild(HorizontalScrollBarTemplateName) as ScrollBar;

    if (scrollBar != null)
        scrollBar.IsStandalone = false;

    // Same for the vertical scroll bar
    // ...
}
```

If a `ScrollViewer` finds scroll bars inside of it, it sets their `IsStandalone` (`internal`) properties to `false`, which disables the scroll command handing of the scroll bars. Instead, the `ScrollViewer` takes over the scroll command handing, but it ignores some `ScrollBar`'s properties, including the `SmallChange` property.

**TL;DR** This won't work for the scroll bars inside of a `ScrollViewer`. You can change your template so use two "external" scroll bars. But then, you will need to connect those scroll bars with the `ScrollViewer` manually.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that your custom control template isn't being used because of the way you are referencing it. I would change the XAML to this:

```
<ScrollViewer>
    <ScrollViewer.Template>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ScrollViewer}">
            <Grid ...>
                ...
            </Grid>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </ScrollViewer.Template>

    ... ScrollViewer content goes here

</ScrollViewer>
```

Basically, set the control's template directly, rather than using a dynamic resource.